# Unable to get the view from controller in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

Hi, I am unable to get the view page after returning model and view below is some code chunks

```
List<GridMappingVO> searchList= gridMappingFacade.validate(gridMappingVO);
if( users.equals(searchList.get(0).getUser()) 
    && passwrd.equals(searchList.get(0).getPass()) ) {
    System.out.println("validation succesfull");
    mv = new ModelAndView("searchResults");
    logger.info("Response is: " + mv);
    mv.addObject("searchList", searchList);
} else {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Invalid");
    map.put("error_messages", list);
    mv.addAllObjects(map);
}
return mv;
```

**STACK TRACE**

```
08:51:31,713  INFO http-8080-1 controller.GridMappingController:45 - Response is: ModelAndView: reference to view with name 'searchResults'; model is null

08:51:31,728 DEBUG http-8080-1 support.DefaultListableBeanFactory:1367 - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'searchResults'
```

Can anyone help me as what is wrong in this?

Answer (score 0):

If your condition is not satisfied, it will go to the else block. so the model will never be instantiated.
Declare the instantiation of the model object outside the if block

```
mv = new ModelAndView("searchResults");
    List<GridMappingVO> searchList= gridMappingFacade.validate(gridMappingVO);
    if( users.equals(searchList.get(0).getUser()) 
    && passwrd.equals(searchList.get(0).getPass()) ) {
    System.out.println("validation succesfull"); 
    logger.info("Response is: " + mv);
    mv.addObject("searchList", searchList);
} else {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Invalid");
    map.put("error_messages", list);
    mv.addAllObjects(map);
}
return mv;
```

You can also do it this way,
instantiate a hashmap at the start of the method
like:

```
Map model = new HashMap();
```

and add the objects to the model.

```
model.put("searchList", searchList);
```

while returning create a new ModelAndView object

```
return new ModelAndView("jsp/searchResults", model)
```

Comment: Check the jsp path passing in the ModelAndView object, it should be the same path in your webapp. Also you need to add the view resolver in the dispatcher servlet

Comment: am not getting any error not even before..it just that searchResults.jsp page is not getting displayed

Comment: ya i am already having view resolver in my servlet how can i check jsp path?

Comment: <bean id="viewResolver"
 class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
 
 <property name="prefix">
  <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
 </property>

 <property name="suffix">
 <value>.jsp</value>
 </property>
 
</bean>

Comment: It is not a standard practice to keep the jsp in the WEB-INF folder, try to move your jsp folder in parallel to the WEB-INF Folder and change your prefix property value to <value>/jsp/</value>

Comment: The webapp should look like this
    customwebapp/WEB-INF/classes/
    customwebapp/jsp/searchResults.jsp

Comment: what do u mean to say i should have one classes folder under web-inf?